# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Product\\Interceptor::_construct()

Tags: magento2

I am getting the following error in my Magento application sometimes, it's not breaking the application always but in regular interval I am getting this error.

The application CPU usage is also going high sometimes. Application is using redis for both caching and session. Database is AWS Aurora.

> [Tue Jul 16 15:41:41.849749 2019] [:error] [pid 6506] [client
>   10.101.8.81:26870] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Interceptor::_construct()
>   in
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php:40\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/AbstractEntity.php(234): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->__construct()\n#1
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php(51):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AbstractEntity->__construct(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Context),
>   Array)\n#2
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product.php(130):
>   Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource->__construct(Object(Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Context),
>   Object(Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager),
>   Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\Factory), Array)\n#3
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/generated/code/Magen in
>   /mnt/drive1/www/magento-2019-07-08-06-50-51/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php
>   on line 40,

Another similar error

> PHP Fatal error:  Couldn't execute method
>   Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader::composer\autoload\classloader::loadclass\x03
>   in Unknown on line 0, referer:

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [clearing generated directories?](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/php/php_clear-dirs.html)

Enable Maintenance Mode, then:

```
rm -rf /path-to-install-dir/generated/code/* /path-to-install-dir/generated/metadata/*
```

After that,

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento cache:clean
```

If you're not in a production environment, you can clear redis cache by running

```
redis-cli:flushall
```

You may need to update/upgrade composer as well.